# Global variable in JQuery is not updating it's value form inside the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery problem. My global variable `xyz` is not updating it's value.
Here I like to change the value of my `xyz` variable.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    .............................
    .............................
    var xyz="testing";
                            function getTest(code) {
                                if(code == 0){
                                    xyz = "I am testing 0";                                     
                                } else if(code == 1){
                                    xyz = "I am testing 1";     
                                }
                            }
```

Now I am calling my `xyz` inside the datatables but it is always printing the global value. i.e. `testing`

```
dt = $('#someTable').dataTable(
                                {
...............
"sTitle" : xyz,

...............
<end of data table function>
```

I am trying to call the function here to update value of my `xyz` variable. Here I am invoking `getTest()`.

```
$("#div").click(function(event) {
........................
...........................
if(code==0){
getTest(code);
} else if (code==1){
getTest(code);
}

<end of all the function>
```

EVERY THING IS INSIDE THE DOCUMENT.READY FUNCTION

Comment: seems to be working, check https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/jbbmbe6j/2/, provide such kind to check your problem

Comment: It's working for me to. But if I am updating inside the click function, It's not working.

Comment: Are you sure your function `getTest` is getting called?
Also you have redundant code in your `click` function

Comment: Are you also sure that you're calling `getTest` with a value of 0 or 1 since there's no catch-all else statement that follows those two. If you can include an example of how you're invoking `getTest`, that would help

Comment: @jmcgriz same here bro. I am going crazy to find this issue. Spent almost 16 Hrs.

Comment: Did you _actually_ tell the datatable to change its title?  Once its visible It won't change automagically just because you changed the contents of `xyz`

Comment: @SuperbSaif That doesn't really help, since you have both calls to getTest in the same if statement. Where is the value of code being set? It's entirely possible that code is undefined or has a value that is neither 0 nor 1

Comment: @jmcgriz value is updating for other function except for this `getTest()`. I think global variable is creating the problem. I am working on towards finding a solution by using local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    .............................
    .............................
    window.xyz="testing";
                            function getTest(code) {
                                if(code == 0){
                                    window.xyz = "I am testing 0";                                     
                                } else if(code == 1){
                                    window.xyz = "I am testing 1";     
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: and now abusing global variables.  There's almost always a better way...

Comment: @Alnitak There is. I am on it. Will post the answer soon. I am trying to not to use global variable but it's difficult to find a way because I am using this variable in three functions. Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: @SuperbSaif so long as _all_ of those functions are within the same lexical scope (i.e. within the `$(document).ready` call) then there's no good reason why they shouldn't be able to access other variables declared within that same scope.